# Is there a reason a wildcard cert won't work vs. single?

Tags: ssl-certificate

**Caveat:**  I'm a developer by trade (so please use small words).

A vendor hosts a secure site for us that is branded with our name/domain, orders.oursite.com.  Since original setup we've purchased a wildcard cert for *.oursite.com.  As I understand it, the basic process for renewing the cert is:

1. Vendor generates CSR from each server.
2. We receive a cert based on each CSR for each server from our certification authority.
3. Vendor installs each cert.

Our vendor (we are an IIS shop/they use Apache) is telling us that we must buy (renew) the specific orders.oursite.com and they can't install a cert that's been generated against *.oursite.com.  Is there any truth to this that my network engineers and I are missing?

**Update**
Under the category of information I could've used in advance, apparently they have some IBM application that prevents use of a wildcard cert.  What it does or how it goes about it, I have no idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not correct.

A wildcard certificate has nothing to do with being able to generate certificates; it is a single certificate that will authenticate all subdomains of the CN the certificate refers to.

So if you purchased a wildcard certificate for *.example.com, that means the web server that runs orders.example.com can use that certificate.

CSRs don't enter into it, as those are used to request a hostname-specific certificate, which you don't want to use.

Replace the `orders` certificate with the wildcard one.

Comment: I had every reason to believe what you've confirmed.  Thank you.

Comment: It is possible to have a single cert ( orders.example.com ) and a wildcard ( *.example.com ). This is especially important if you want to use *.example.com, but have a 3rd party host your shop ( orders.example.com ) or your cdn ( cdn.example.com ) or statistics ( stats.example.com ).